# in security-context only access a page when redirect

Tags: java, spring

I have a security-context.xml who controls the acces of the different pages of my website. Now I want that the pages in the folder L0 are only accessible for Admin-user. So I add the following line:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/L0/**" access="hasRole('L1_Users') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

Now I want that those pages are accessible for the users when there are redirected from another page. For example a user who has access to L1 can't call the page /L0/pageName.jsp but can access it by browing to a page /L1/pageName.jsp that redirect to /L0/pageName.jsp

Can I put a line in the security-context.xml to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To multiple user ,please use

```
     access="hasAnyRole('L1_Users','ROLE_USER')"
```

Comment: I don't want the L1_Users to be able to access directly the L0 level. It can only access when it is redirect to it from another page !

Comment: I think you should use server side flag,If redirect <c:if test=${redirect}>  // see </c:if>